# Fedora 13 loads without GUI after installing Gnome Environment

Tags: login, gnome, graphical-user-interface, fedora

I have had a Fedora box that serves as a development box, it started with Fedora Core 6 and has been upgraded over a few years and now has Fedora 13. After Fedora 9 I switched to mode 3 or text-only mode since then I have become familiar with the command line and never needed the GUI. I now have an application I want to develop but I have to adjust something graphically so I switched back to mode 5. However, when I reboot I only get a blank screen and no GUI login screen. I thought I would run `yum groupinstall "X Window System" "GNOME Desktop Environment` and it ran smoothly. I reboot and still the blank screen.

Why am I getting the blank screen and how can I get Gnome's GUI login screen to appear?

Comment: What's in /var/log/Xorg.0.log ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking MadHatter's suggestion, I checked the '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' file and found a virtual resolution entry that I put there years ago for VNC use. I commented it out and the GUI reappeared.